# Remove ethernet network device not managed the Ubuntu interface

Tags: networking, interface

These devices appear out of nowhere in Ubuntu 16.04 and since then could not remove. The following pictures:
[image]
Does anyone know how to remove?

Comment: Could you please post the contents of your `/etc/network/interfaces` file?

Comment: My interfaces file content:
_auto lo
iface lo inet loopback_

Comment: I've seen this same issue since upgrading to 16.04.  In my case it's because of Docker (others see the same with vbox and similar).  Running `nmcli d` for me shows 5 devices named like "veth024a9eb", where each shows in nm-applet as in your screenshot.  I have not yet figured out how to have nm-applet omit them though.  Hopefully this can provide a bit more to go on.

Comment: You can check for these interfaces in output of `ifconfig` command. These ethernet interfaces' names will give you some clue about their source.

Comment: I wore a wifi adapter and each time used a new connection was created , I could not remove the list of adapters. In 'ipconfig' they are not listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug entry on Launchpad which describes the problem. Please follow-up here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1458322